# jQuery.shapeshift - Container within container

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to get jQuery.shapeshift working with a "shapeshift" container that is located within another "shapeshift" container, i.e:

```
<div class="container1">
    <div class="container2"></div>
</div>
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/LNysC/1429/

Apparently jQuery.shapeshift does not support it. (Or am I doing something wrong?)

Is there another way (or library) to get it working?